# Using matchMedia, window resize to fix a responsive browsing edge case

Tags: javascript

Any help would be most appreciated.

I hide the site navigation, behind a burger menu which toggles the styles. For users who have a screen/device `@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)`

Everyone else, the navigation is always present.

When you resize/shrink a Desktop browser to be the mobile query, click on the burger menu and hide it. THEN expand the window; the navigation is hidden on the larger screen.

I've written a small script using mediaMatch; to force its appearance. however, when both conditions are true it does not run.

Console output - separate checks for the two conditions

> mql.matches && getStyle('.header_burger_container', 'display') === 'none'

> true

```
    const getStyle = (el, at) => {
      let get = document.querySelector(el);
      let style = getComputedStyle(get).getPropertyValue(at);
      return style;
    }
```

```
    let mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 751px)');
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      if (mql.matches == 'true' && getStyle('.header_burger_container', 'display') === 'none') {
        document.querySelector('.header_burger_container').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.header_burger_container ul').style.display = 'block';
      }
    }, false);
```

Would you have any advice to remedy the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue; in earnest I am not sure why my solution worked. :s

Seperating the function body from the event listener worked first time.

```
    const res_nav_resize = () => {
      if (mql.matches && getStyle('.header_burger_container', 'display') === 'none') {
        document.querySelector('.header_burger_container').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.header_burger_container ul').style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', res_nav_resize);
```

Which was inspired by the [Mozilla window.resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) documentation.